# What does model_dir refers to in TensorFlow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

```
# Build 3 layer DNN with 10, 20, 10 units respectively.
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                              hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                                              n_classes=3,
                                              model_dir="/tmp/iris_model")
```

What does **`model_dir`** refer to?

After running the program, I am unable to find `/tmp/iris_model`.

This snippet is taken from: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/tflearn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `model_dir` arguments represents the directory to save model parameters, graph and etc. This can also be used to load checkpoints from the directory into a estimator to continue training a previously saved model.

In your case, your model is saved in the system temporary directory and subject to be deleted/cleaned by the system and that's why you can't find it.

I advice you to read the DNNClassifier doc [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/DNNClassifier).

Comment: So is this directory deleted after the program is completed?

Comment: Well if it stays in /tmp/ it should be deleted by the system at some point. To understand how that works, please read the answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20783/how-is-the-tmp-directory-cleaned-up)

Comment: Oh right, I forgot it is an absolute path. I was looking in the project folder. No wonder I couldn't find it. Thanks!

Comment: How can I save it without rerunning the training?